# Query set for many to many object relationship

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, http-post, many-to-many, django-queryset

Need to post many items onetime -many titles- in a titles list from mobile app to the backend, the problem is when use create method within the for loop it gets no record in database & that Type Error -Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use container.set() instead.-   when try to use the set() method it's not showing any right case!!!!, the problem is when to use create in order to made many create objects in many-to-many relationship. please guide.

models.py

```
class Container(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    capacity = models.IntegerField( null=False ,blank=False)


class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    container = models.ManyToManyField(container)
```

serializers.py

```
class ContainerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Container
        fields = '__all__'

class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = '__all__'
```

Request

```
{
"container": {
        "name": "container1",
        "capacity": 10,
         },
"Items":[
    {"title":"tl1",},
    {"title":"tl2",},
    {"title":"tl3",}
    ]
}
```

view.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def additems(request):

    data = request.data
    
    container = Container.objects.create(
        name = data['name']
        capacity = data['capacity']
        )
    container.save()


    for i in Items:

        item = Item.objects.create(
        container = container ,
        title = i['title'] ,    
                  )
        item.save()

    serializer = ContainerSerializer(container, many=False)
    return response(serializer.data)
```

TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use container.set() instead.
Why getting this error ?!!! please guide ...

Comment: This error is result of you trying to direct assign object to m2m set, you should use set method instead

Comment: thank you, I edited the many-to-many relation and used the set method & it's done.